# Overwriting an array entry when it has a duplicate key

Tags: c#, arrays, list, key

I'm writing a small programm right now in which I made a Paar class, where one object consists of a key and a value

```
class Paar
{
    private object value1;

    public Paar(string key, object value1)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value1;
    }

    public string key;
    public object value;
}
```

I made a Put and a Get method for the class. The Put method parses a new entry in the first open slot it finds and the Get method can be used to print an entry by calling the key, they're as following

```
    private Paar[] getArray = new Paar[10];

    public void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (getArray[i] == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    throw new Exception("All slots full");
                }
            }
        }
        getArray[i] = new Paar(key, value);
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            Paar currentElement = getArray[i]

            if (currentElement.key == key)
            { 
                return currentElement.value;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid key");
    }
```

"Problem" is, that when I have two entries with the same key, I can only print the first entry, while I'd like to add a function to the Put method that overwrites previous entries with the same key and prints the most recent entry.

E.g:

```
newMap.Put("Key2", "Value1"); newMap.Put("Key2", "Value2"); newMap.Put("Key2", "Value3");
Console.WriteLine(newMap.Get("Key2"));
```

would currently print Value1, while I'd like it to print Value3. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array rather than a Dictionary?

Comment: Was tasked to use an object array

Comment: Can you ask them why they asked you to do it that way? Your problem space is **perfect** for a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented tchelidze's answer since it was technically correct, but when later implementing a Remove method it didn't work properly all the time since it could also parse the duplicate key's entry into an empty slot if there happened to be one before the duplicate key's slot, because it either checked for an empty slot or a matching key. So I improved the function to go through two seperate loops.

```
public void Put(string key, object value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (getArray[i] != null && getArray[i].key == key)
        {
            getArray[i] = new Paar(key, value);
            return;
        }         
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < getArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (getArray[i] == null)
            {
                getArray[i] = new Paar(key, value);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i >= getArray.Length)
                {
                    throw new Exception("All slots full");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
 public void Put(string key, object value)
 {
    for (var i = 0; i < getArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (getArray[i] == null || getArray[i].key == key)
        {
            getArray[i] = new Paar(key, value);
            break;
        }
        if(i == getArray.Length - 1)
            throw new Exception("All slots full");
    }
 }
```